# I'm not sure why my code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on an assignment question. How do I make my code work?

```
var myObj = {
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  // Your Code Here
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkObj) === true) {
return  myObj[checkObj];
} else return "Not Found";
}
myObj.hasOwnProperty(""); 
// Test your code by modifying these values
checkObj("gift");
```

Comment: Poorly worded question. What is the code supposed to do? What result are you expecting? What result are you getting? What have you tried to do to debug and what were the results of that effort?

Answer (score 3):

Check your variable names

```
var myObj = {
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  // Your Code Here       vv HERE vv
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp) === true) {
return  myObj[checkProp];  // <= and here
} else return "Not Found";
}
myObj.hasOwnProperty(""); 
// Test your code by modifying these values
checkObj("gift");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are wrong and you're missing braces on your `if/else` statement.

Try this:

```
var myObj = {
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp) === true) { //checkProp, not checkObj
    return myObj[checkProp]; //checkProp, not checkObj
  } else { // you were missing this opening brace
    return "Not Found";
  }
}

myObj.hasOwnProperty("");
alert(checkObj("gift"));
```

See [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gx85pyk/).